How to run RSpec system specs with Dev Containers
I'm trying to set up DevContainers with a Rails 7.2 app, but I'm having difficulties getting my RSpec system specs to run correctly.
My compose.yaml file includes the selenium/standalone-chromium image to run Chrome.
name: "my_app"

services:
  rails-app:
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: .devcontainer/Dockerfile

    volumes:
    - ../..:/workspaces:cached

    # Use "forwardPorts" in **devcontainer.json** to forward an app port locally.
    # (Adding the "ports" property to this file will not forward from a Codespace.)
    depends_on:
    - postgres
    - selenium

  postgres:
    image: postgres:16.1
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
    - default
    volumes:
    - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres

  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chromium
    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
  postgres-data:

I have updated my Capybara config as follows:
config.before(:each, type: :system) do
  driven_by :selenium, using: :chrome, options
    browser: :remote,
    url: "http://selenium:4444"
  }
end

But I get the following error
Failure/Error: visit(violations_path)
          
          Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
            unable to connect to /home/vscode/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/128.0.6613.119/chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9515

What am I missing here?
I have tried to find some information online but nothing came out.

UPDATE -
It looks to me the Selenium server is reachable from the rails app

$ curl --dump-header - http://selenium:4444
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
content-length: 0
Location: /ui/

$ curl -L  http://selenium:4444
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <link href="favicon.svg" rel="icon" type="image/svg">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
  <link href="logo192.png" rel="apple-touch-icon"/>
  <link href="manifest.json" rel="manifest"/>
  <title>Selenium Grid</title>
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>


UPDATE 2
I have updated the Selenium image I use to selenium/standalone-chromium:4.24.0, the same version of my  selenium-webdriver (4.24.0), and now I get the same error, but first I get

2024-09-09 08:57:20 ERROR Selenium Exception occurred: Unsuccessful command executed: ["/home/vscode/.rbenv/versions/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.24.0/bin/linux/selenium-manager", "--browser", "chrome", "--language-binding", "ruby", "--output", "json"] - Code 65
{"code"=>65, "message"=>"error decoding response body", "driver_path"=>"", "browser_path"=>""}

I tried to understand what the error meant, but I couldn't find it.
